# Gem error when Installing ruby 1.9.2 on CentOS 5.4 via RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I installed RVM 1.6.5 on my Centos 5.4.  Everything went well, but when I try and use the gem command I get the error.

usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:28:in `': uninitialized constant Gem::ConfigFile (NameError)

I cant seem to find any answers on google for this error.  Ruby was installed as root.  Does anyone have any idea on how I would start troubleshooting this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Well I used ruby 1.9.2-p0 and it now all works. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

You have to completely remove rvm, reinstall it and install 1.8.7 before 1.9.2-head

```
rvm implode
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm use 1.8.7
rvm --default install 1.9.2-head
```

Answer (score -1):

looking at the path you posted, it looks like you tried to install some Ruby 1.9.1 gems underneath Ruby 1.9.2, 
e.g. using Ruby 1.9.2 as the default ruby version... weird... that looks really odd!

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/**ruby-1.9.2-p180**/lib/ruby/site_ruby/**1.9.1**/rubygems/config_file.rb:28:in